# How to remove predefined facebook-messenger questions in the new environment please?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger

how I can remove predefined facebook-messenger questions in the new environment please?
I checked Automatic Responses in the Meta Business suite but there isn't anything related to predefined questions.
Can you please help me?

[image]
[image][image]